# Why do .Net applications receive WM_NCHITTEST twice?

Tags: .net, winapi

I'm doing a function that seamless simulates the messages generated by SendInput.

So far i'm sending WM_NCHITTEST to the window.
Then WM_SETCURSOR with the result of the hit test.
And finally WM_MOUSEMOVE.

But some windows (ie: visualstudio, .net ones) receive a sequence of 2 or more identical WM_NCHITTEST.

How can i know how many hit tests are sent to a window?

```
/*Example from vstudio 2010:*/
<15008> 000E030E S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:509 yPos:543   //1st
<15009> 000E030E R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTCLIENT
<15010> 000E030E S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:509 yPos:543   //2nd
<15011> 000E030E R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTCLIENT
<15012> 000E030E S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000E030E nHittest:HTCLIENT wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE
<15013> 000E030E R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False
<15014> 000E030E P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:0000 xPos:509 yPos:543
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/18/10131176.aspx might offer some insights.

Comment: thx, but it doesn't explain what's going on in windows side when it sends duplicate WM_NCHITTEST.

Comment: Why does it matter to you how many WM_NCHITTEST messages the windows receives? In a normal (non-SendInput) scenario, the window will get several of these as the user moves the mouse cursor over the non-client areas of the window.

Comment: SendInput doesn't generate any messages.  Windows processing the input event does.  Hard to see what it has to do with WM_NCHITTEST.

Comment: Different versions of Windows may behave differently here.  I don't think there is any guarantee as to how often and in what order WM's are sent, unless explicitly stated in the documentation.

Comment: I'm assuming that all WM_NCHITTEST are sent from windows, normally once per WM_SetCursor, sometimes it sends multiple times and in other cases it keeps sending while the mouse is over an window even when the mouse isn't moving. Each of these behaviors must be triggered by something, by what?

Answer (score -1):

The Windows OS or any application may send `WM_NCHITTEST` for any coordinate anytime it needs to inquire about the geometry of your window. If your code makes any assumptions at all about when it is called, your code is wrong.

In theory, "Because I felt like it" is a valid answer to "why did you send `WM_NCHITTEST`."

In the broad sense, simulating `SendInput()` by `SendMessage()` doesn't work right. You should stop trying to do that.